# Sling Post Request creating child nodes

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

Since you can post with sling via form with content application/x-www-urlformencoded. This seems to able to create only one node. If my encoded form has child nodes, how should the encoding look?

```
&./firstnode=value&./secondNode=value
```

If I want the secondNode to be the child of the first node, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

think of all the parameter names as subpaths of the node you're posting to. by default, a single slash would denote a property:

```
./property=value
```

to specify a node, you need to set a value under the target node:

```
./subnode/property=value
```

i think `nt:unstructured` is used by default in these cases, but you can explicitly set the nodetype by

```
./subnode/jcr:primaryType=TYPE&./subnode/property=val&...
```

Answer (score -1):

ALL nodes that have to be created must be treated independently (counting parent nodes), even if the node is only a parent and doesn't have properties of its own.  I am not confident that you can build an entire tree with a single post, because you usually need to save the parent before adding children.

The Sling website has a section on [multipart/form-data POSTs](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#preface-multipartform-data-posts) for more details.